# how can i fix this error for drumboiler example

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

How can I fix this error for drumboiler example?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of hard to answer questions without the model code, but based on the error with `Cv.from_bar` my guess is that you copied some code containing that from MSL (Modelica Standard Library - shown to the left in your package browser) for the boiler.

The likely corrections are:

- Replace `Cv.from_bar` by `Modelica.Units.Conversions.from_bar` in the parameter-dialog of some component (sink?).
- In Modelica text for this model add `import Cv=Modelica.Units.Conversions;`
- If the models aren't directly from MSL they may contain errors.

Comment: Regarding "Replace `Cv.from_bar` by `Modelica.Units.Conversions.from_bar` in the parameter-dialog of boiler.":  
I think it should be "Replace `Cv.from_bar` by `Modelica.Units.Conversions.from_bar` in the parameter-dialog of `sink`."

Comment: Hmm... I understand. It's the entire model that is called 'boiler' - it's not a sub-component.

Comment: I copied the code from DrumBoiler example from library and when I run it this error occurs @HansOlsson

Comment: If you look at the enclosing class Modelica.Fluid you find the same import Cv=Modelica.Units.Conversions; I don't know if OpenModelica can handle that automatically in some way. In Dymola just doing "Copy Class" for DrumBoiler handles it.

Comment: If this answer solves the issue you can mark it as 'Accepted' using the check-box below the vote-numbers